# Twilio Outgoing Calls Failed Code 31002

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twilio

I keep getting error code 31002 in Twilio without know how to debug. I use client JS and Ruby on Rails as my backend.

First of all, what I'm going to do is to create apps that can make voice call from my browser to mobile phone.

Please see image below for the error I got on my browser:

[image]

Comment: `31002`? i dont see that error code https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice-sdk/error-codes

Comment: The error codes come from client itself. Can read the error codes here  twilio.com/docs/api/client/errors it said "Connection declined. Check the debugger for more information on the actual cause." but i cannot find any actual cause @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: it tells you to look into the `details` field for more information on the error  **31002 : A required parameter was not passed with the request. The error object's detail field will provide more information as to what field was missing.**

Comment: I think readers will need to see more information to understand what's wrong here (indeed, error messages should be posted as text, not images - could you edit?).

Answer (score 5):

The 31002 error code is returned by Twilio API. Here are some troubleshooting steps to rule out basic errors:

1. Check the debugger page on your Twilio console https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/debugger. If you don't see the call in the log, it's likely that you are looking at the wrong Twilio account/subaccount/project. Project is on the left of the top action bar, subaccount is on the right.
   [image: twilio action bar]
2. Go to the console dashboard https://www.twilio.com/console, check if your application is using the correct `TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID` and `TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN`
3. Go to Programmable voice https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/twiml/apps, check if you are using the correct application SID
4. Go to Phone numbers https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming, check if you are using the right number.

My experience, the rule of thumb is, if you don't see any activity on the Twilio debugger page, you are probably using the wrong SID/token/etc.